# How to unit test React functions passed in as prop to child component with Enzyme shallow wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am very new to front-end dev & I am having some trouble getting my Enzyme unit tests using Shallow. Basically, I have something like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        const {
            handleClick,
            ...other
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="someClass">
                // a bunch of stuff
                <div className="buttonArea">
                    <MyComponentChild onClick={handleClick} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    MyComponent.propTypes = {
        handleClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        ...other
    };

    export default MyComponent;
}
```

handleClick is a callback function defined in the container (i.e ComponentContainer) that MyComponent belongs to. I am passing it as a prop into MyComponent, and subsequently MyComponentChild (which is a button component). I want to test whether handleClick fires when MyComponentChild is clicked.

My current Enzyme test

```
it('handleClick should fire when clicked', () => {
    const mockCallbackFn = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {handleClick = { mockCallbackFn }} />);
    wrapper.find('MyComponentChild').simulate('click');
    expect(mockCallbackFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, this test is currently failing, as mockCallbackFn is apparently never called. But, this is also passing

```
expect(wrapper.find('MyComponentChild').prop('handleClick')).toEqual(mockCallbackFn);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`simulate(someEventName)` does really simple thing: it calls prop with name of `"on" + someEventName`. So `simulate('click')` runs `.props().onClick()`.

But your component uses `handleClick` prop, that's why it does not called by `simulate()`

```
wrapper.find('MyComponentChild').props().handleClick();
```

Name `simulate` is so confusing that team is going to remove it out(https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2173).

Side note: you don't need extra braces when declaring props. I mean `{handleClick = { mockCallbackFn }}` better be `handleClick={mockCallbackFn}` since it's typical for React code and looks less confusing.

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mount` instead of `shallow`. `shallow` only mounts the first level of components, so your `ComponentChild` is not being mounted and your click handler isn't being passed in.

You can see this yourself by calling `debug()` on your `wrapper` and `console.log`-ing it.